# how does the console.log omit spaces in the array?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log( '"' +[ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry' ] + '"' )
```

Hello everyone, can someone please expalin how does the console.log() omits the spaces in the array ?

The output should look like that : `"apple,orange,banana,strawberry"`

How does the console.log do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the console, it's [`Array#toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring), which calls [`Array#join`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.join) with no arguments, so `Array#join` defaults the separator to `","`. `Array#toString` is being called because you're using `+` on a string and an array, which will coerce the array to string before doing the concatenation.

Example using `join` explicitly:

```js
var str = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry'].join();
console.log(str);
```